# Sudden change from 'localhost' to 'www.localhost.com' PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

I have various applications and single scripts that is running successufully in XAMPP - simple schema root folder(htdocs) == `http://localhost/` or just `localhost/`

I have downloaded some Wordpress site and moved it into apropriate folder: it was www.example.com/blog and I have moved it into htdocs/blog. I was doing all right (files and folders recursive search and replace, searchandreplacedb2.php routine) and result was:

**typed: `http://localhost/blog/`**

**got:   `http://www.localhost.com/blog/`**

with Firefox notice :

> The connection was reset
>
> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

*Notices:*
1. I have tried with removing existing .htaccess,
2. recursive search&replace wordpress files did not had any case `www.example.com/blog/` with `localhost/blog` (it usually have).

Comment: Check in the `wp_options` table for `siteurl` and `home`. Modify if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about adding this lines to your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Also, check your database. You might have the wrong URL in some tables.

Cheers